# How to multiply a combo box and a text box value in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox, textbox, multiplication

I have no code so far because I don't know how to start off.I have a combo box called cboDrink and a Text box called txtNoDrinks. I would like to multiply the values from the combo box with the entered number from the text box. The final answer will be in a message box.

Comment: what values contains cboDrinks? you can't multiply mojitos with numbers!

Comment: I want to set the price for them and multiply that with another number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cboDrinks` you can set .[`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with drinks names and .[`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with drinks prices.

Then you can use a similar code:

```
Msgbox(CDbl(Me.cboDrinks.SelectedValue) * CInt(Me.txtNoDrinks.Text))
```